# visual studio extensibilty - How can I check if Silverlight debugging is enabled in an ASP.NET Web Site?

Tags: silverlight, vsx, envdte, visual-studio-extensions

How can I programatically check whether a Web Site has Silverlight debugging enabled (ie, whether the "Silverlight" checkbox under "Property Pages->Start Options" is checked)?

I know that for a Web **Application** (WAP), I can check this via EnvDTE ( by checking `project.Properties.Item("WebApplication.SilverlightDebugging").Value`), but for a Web **Site**, I can't find an equivalent property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Web Site project, there are properties named EnableASPXDebugging, EnableUnmanagedDebugging, and EnableSQLServerDebugging, but strangely there is no EnableSilverlightDebugging property. This might be a bug in Visual Studio.

Properties for Web Site projects are saved to the following file:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\Websites.xml

As a last resort, you can parse the file and read the value of the `enablesilverlightdebugging` attribute for your particular `<Website>`. Unfortunately, it seems that this file does not get updated until the project is closed, so the file may be out of sync with the actual setting.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea about how I could possibly force a refresh of the Websites.xml file?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You might want to open an issue on Microsoft Connect and see what they say.